# how to get random array of double type from ArrayList<double[]> in java

Tags: java

I have declared one variable of type `ArrayList<Double[]>`. I want to get random double array k times from this.Please help me with this. Thanks.

This is the declearation: `ArrayList<Double[]> vecspace = new ArrayList<double[]>();` From this I need to access arrays one by one(not numbers). If not possible please tell me other way of declaring "vecspace" to get random arrays.

Comment: Please note that: variable is ""ArrayList<double[]> variable""

Comment: Please show us your starting/code so that the SO Community can help you

Comment: arrayList class cannot generate random double numbers

Comment: This is the declearation: ArrayList<double[]> vecspace = new ArrayList<double[]>();  From this I need to access arrays one by one(not numbers). If not possible please tell me other way of declaring "vecspace" to get random arrays. Thanks.

Comment: use the Random class and use the get method of the ArrayList class, since each element of your ArrayList is a double[]

Comment: doing `vecspace.get(0);` will return double array at position 0

Answer (score 0):

By using the Random class and the get method of your ArrayList you can achieve such a goal

First I would wrote a method that allows me to get an integer between 0 and the size of your ArrayList in a random fashion

Declare a Random instance as final at class level

```
 final Random random = new Random(0)

// Call this with n = your ArrayList.size()
public static int integerBetweenZeroAnd (int n) {

    return random.nextInt(n);

}
```

If I have
    `ArrayList<Double[]> myArrayList = new ArrayList<Double[]>();`

from this you call:

```
Double[] randomlyPickedArray =   myArrayList.get(integerBetweenZeroAnd(myArrayList.size()));
```

Comment: This will get the same array everytime. You need to either keep a common `Random` instance in your class, or not give a seed in the constructor (ie `Random random = new Random()`).

Comment: I'd also put the whole thing in a `getRandomArray` method. Your `integerBet...` method just replicates `Random`'s `nextInt`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Collections.shuffle()` method to effectively randomise the Double arrays in your ArrayList, then get the first array from the list using `get()`, like this:

```
Collections.shuffle(vecspace);
Double[] randomArray = vecspace.get(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

To generate a "random" value (not really random as explained in [Pseudorandomness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandomness) and [Pseudorandom Number Generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator)) you have to use `java.util.Random` for `values of a specific range or` java.lang.Math.random()`for`Double`s with value between 0.0 and 1.0.

## `java.lang.Random`:

```
Random randGen = new Random()
for(int i=0; i<k; i++) {
  int randomIndex = randGen.nextInt(array.size() -1); // generates a random value between 0 and (size of array - 1) 
  Double[] randomSelected = array.get(randomIndex);
}
```

## `java.lang.Math.random()`:

```
for(int i=0; i<k; i++){
  Double[] random = array.get((int)(java.lang.Math.random * (array.size() -1)));
}
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, you always should provide some explanation for why it does so.